# Toggling an element with JQuery makes part of the parent element dissapear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a nav bar with jquery, fairly simple, clicking the nav icon brings up a menu on the side, however I need a sub-menu to appear after clicking one of the options, in this case the "equipment we sell" tab. I have no problem with that as I click the tab and it toggles the menu to being visible however, all of the tabs below it become invisible (I'm assuming they don't relocate to below the now visible element). Can someone explain to me why the tabs do not make room for the new list elements. Code below.

**jscript**

```
$('.icon-menu').click(function() {

  $('.menu').animate({
    right: '0px'
    }, 200);
  $('.equipsell').hide();
});

$('.menu-exit').click(function() {
  $('.menu').animate({
    right: '-285px'
  }, 200);
  $('.equipsell').hide();
});

$('.equipment').click(function() {
  $('.equipsell').toggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="menu">
    <img src="img/menu-exit.png" class="menu-exit" alt="Exit Button">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="equipment"><a href="#">Equipment We Sell</a></li>
        <div class="equipsell">
            <li><a href="inventis_audio.html">Audiometers by Inventis</a></li>
            <li><a href="inventis_middle.html">Middle Ear Analyzers by Inventis</a></li>
            <li><a href="inventis_delfino.html">Delfino Video Otoscopes by Inventis</a></li>
            <li><a href="inventis_daisy.html">Daisy by Inventis</a></li>
            <li><a href="inventis_trumpet.html">Trumpet REM by Inventis</a></li>
        </div>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="main-menu">
    <a href="index.php"><p>Test<br>Website</p></a>
    <img src="img/bars.jpg" class="icon-menu" alt="Menu">
    </div>

</header>
```

So when you click the equipment class/list item from above it lowers down the "menu" class but covers up the contact us list item.

**EDIT**

Forgot to include css.

**CSS**

```
    /***** NAV *****/

    header {
        background-color: #093;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    header p {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1.35em;
        margin: 10px 0 5px 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 3px solid black;
    }

    header a {
        color: black;
    }

    .icon-menu {
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        float: right;
        margin: 20px 15px 0 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .menu {
        background: #00882B;
        right: -285px;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        width: 285px;
    }

    .menu-exit {
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        margin-left: 48%;
    }

    .menu ul {
        border-top: 1px solid #636363;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .menu li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #636363;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        line-height: 45px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 3px;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 800;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .menu a {
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 800;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .active-menu{
        position: absolute;
    }

    .equipsell{
        width: 285px;
        position: fixed;
    }

    .equipsell li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 2.5;
        background-color: #c90;
    }

    .equipsell a{
        color: white;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .bottom-half li {
        background-color: #00882B;
    }

    /***************/
```

Comment: Provide css or a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1113/) pls

Comment: The only tag allowed as a direct child of the UL element is LI so you should move your equipsell div into an LI. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `.equipsell` is defining the position to be `fixed`, which causes is to be placed a layer above the other elements.

I guess the code to create the expected result would be:

`.equipsell{
  width: 285px;
}`

JSFiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/rc8br5oe/

More about the CSS positions: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp